How to emulate pgfplots's surf layering/shading in plain tikz
I want to emulate pgfplots shading and layering from its \addplot3[surf] {f(x,y)}; command in plain tikz.
I want to do this so I can make more sophisticated graphs that are based on separate functions.
For example, here are a few spheres I've made; the goal is to draw the inner sphere so it hides the outer sphere, similar to in the first diagram:

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz-3dplot}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[hide axis, axis equal]
\addplot3[domain=0:270,surf] ({cos(x)*sin(y)},{sin(x)*sin(y)},{(cos(y)});
\addplot3[domain=0:360,surf] ({0.35*cos(x)*sin(y)},{0.35*sin(x)*sin(y)},{(0.35*cos(y)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{45}{45}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
%%% OUTER SPHERE %%%
%%% LINES OF LONGITUDE %%%
\foreach \Vn in {0,10,...,270}{
\draw[domain=0:180,smooth,variable=\Vt] plot ({cos(\Vn)*sin(\Vt)},{sin(\Vn)*sin(\Vt)},{cos(\Vt)});}
%%% LINES OF LATITUTE %%%
\foreach \Vn in {0,10,...,180}{
\draw[domain=0:270,smooth,variable=\Vt] plot ({cos(\Vt)*sin(\Vn)},{sin(\Vt)*sin(\Vn)},{cos(\Vn)});}
%%% INNER SPHERE %%%
%%% LINES OF LONGITUDE %%%
\foreach \Vn in {0,10,...,270}{
\draw[domain=0:180,smooth,variable=\Vt] plot ({0.35*cos(\Vn)*sin(\Vt)},{0.35*sin(\Vn)*sin(\Vt)},{0.35*cos(\Vt)});}
%%% LINES OF LATITUTE %%%
\foreach \Vn in {0,10,...,180}{
\draw[domain=0:360,smooth,variable=\Vt] plot ({0.35*cos(\Vt)*sin(\Vn)},{0.35*sin(\Vt)*sin(\Vn)},{0.35*cos(\Vn)});}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Search for 'functional shading' in the tikz manual as I guess that's the kind of thing you are thinking of. But I don't think pgf/tikz is the best tool for this as it doesn't know anything about 3d, whereas other tools do. So it can probably be done with enough effort, but there are probably better ways to go. Or maybe use gnuplot, which tikz supports?

@cfr I see, maybe this is a good time to learn Asymptote - I've always been meaning to

I do not understand your goal. PGFPlots is on top of TikZ. Sure you can do everything without PGFPlot, -just figure out how PGFPlots do it and do it the same way. You would not gain anything by that. You need to show an example of these "more sophisticated graphs" that PGFPlots can not do.

You most probably do not want functional shading it is mean to shade an area where the shading is given by a function. -it is not for mesh graphs. With functional shading everything is left to the renderer - there are several warnings in the manual -it is slow -it is not well supported. I do not believe that PGFPlots uses it anywhere.

@hpekristiansen, thank you for your elaborations. To clarify, by more sophisticated graphs, I mean graphs where there are at least two separate surfaces in which each one is "on top" in different parts of the graph. Regarding your comment about learning how PGFPlots does it - I think that is probably the way to go. Obviously it must be possible, as it can do it for individual surfaces. I will look into how PGFPlots codes its surface function and try to accomplish this.

Yes PGFPlots does not have a z-buffer that extends outside of plots. But neither does TikZ. Nothing is gained by not using PGFPlots. If the mentioned areas can be functional described, it can be done manually. You could ask about it and I will help. As is, this question is not answerable as there is no meaningful goal.

You “just” need to split up the thing into layers: the viewable inner part of the outer sphere is in the background, the viewable outer part of the inner sphere comes next, and on top is the viewable outer part of the outer sphere. Of course it may not be trivial to split things up …
